# How can I update a Select when another Select's value changes?

Tags: jsf

So my program is supposed to receive inputs from a Java Beans file which will then output that data to an existing Select box, but only when another select boxes selected values change. How can I do this? Here is my existing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>Dropdown List</title>
</h:head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
        <h:outputText value="#{helloWorld.getResultSet1()}" escape="false" />
        <f:attribute name="action" value="1" />
    </select>
    <br />

    <h:form id="formId">
        <h:inputHidden id="x" value="#{helloWorld.text}" />
        <h:commandButton id="y" value="read" action="#{helloWorld.submit()}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <div id="i">
        <select id="mySelect1">

        </select>
    </div>
    <p id="u"></p>

    <script>
        var x1 = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
        x1.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("formId:y").style.display = 'none';

        function myFunction() {

            var x = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
            document.getElementById("formId:x").value = x;
            document.getElementById("formId:y").click();

            var t = "#{helloWorld.getResultSet2()}";
            document.getElementById("u").innerHTML = t;
            x1.style.display = 'block';



        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the comment on the other questions......

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot easily with the code you provided... This is **not** what JSF is and how JSF should be used. Start using a real good JSF tutorial...